# Spring State Machine send-event returns true when guard is false

Tags: java, spring-boot, state-machine, spring-statemachine

I'm implementing a state machine with Spring Boot SM. One of the transitions only happens when a Guard constraint is successful:

```
.withExternal().source(ProjectStatus.STATE2).target(StatutProjet.STATE3).event(ProjectEvent.next).guard(quoteSelected());
```

when I send an event :

```
if (stateMachine.sendEvent(message)) {
   // Event is accepted so I could return OK response
} else {
   // Event is not accepted so I could return some error handling process
}
```

The event is accepted even if the guard returns false and the transition doesn't happen. This is a problem because this behaviour looks like I'm having a self-target transition.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Accepting event does not mean the processing event itself. Here, returning boolean value Spring tells you *based on the current state of SM I can accept this event for further validation and processing*. 
You should consider a state machine as an async component because all guards and actions are executed in special task executor. 
See [Transition Action Error Handling](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/reference/#statemachine-config-transition-actions-errorhandling) for detailes.

In your case, as I understand you need to give immediate feedback to the initiator of the event. I can suggest you use [State Machine](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/api/org/springframework/statemachine/StateMachine.html)'s `setStateMachineError` and `hasStateMachineError` methods to get that feedback.